# How do I install KDE 3.5 or TDE?

Tags: kde, desktop-environments

I have a machine with low memory, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with classic gnome, but I would like to install kde 3.5 or TDE (fork).

Comment: why KDE 3.5? is not actively developed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Kubuntu desktop (KDE) running this command on a terminal (Dash - Search Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

It uses KDE 4.8, but I don't see what's the reason for downgrading to KDE 3.5.

I hope it helped you.